# What kind of compression algorithm is this?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, compression

So I have a couple of compressed files, and the uncompressed versions as well. I do not have the software that created these files originally. I'm trying to figure out what the underlying algorithm is -- can you figure it out? Initially, I thought it might be some LZW variant, but I'm not sure. The data seems to make more sense when broken up into 6-bit words -- I see lots of repeating patterns then.

The two files are very similar, and the uncompressed versions differ by only a few bytes -- that could help establish where those differing bytes are in the compressed files. I've highlighted the differences.

Compressed file #1:

```
02 02 01 17 0E 11 92 14 C0 55 52 44 FF BC AE 47 DB E1 05 42 F8 70 DE 57 23 FF
54 1A 55 3D BF 54 10 E3 38 0C B2 FB C4 92 1C 20 DE 57 23 FF 54 1A 55 3D BE 5E
4C 96 B2 0E 32 80 CB 2F BC 48 70 83 79 5C 8F FD 50 69 54 F6 F9 96 48 A9 07 19
C2 30 F0 E1 BC AE 47 FE A8 34 AA 7B 7E 32 BF E5 1F EE A8 48 CA 11 87 87 0D E5
72 3F F5 41 A5 53 DB E5 24 5D F8 CA FF 4C B1 13 8C 71 18 7B C3 86 F2 B9 1F FA
A0 D2 A9 ED FD 55 97 BA 22 32 C0 CB 2F BC
```

Compressed file #2:

```
02 02 01 17 0E 11 92 14 C0 55 52 44 FF BC AE 47 DB E1 05 42 F8 70 DE 57 23 FF
54 1A 55 3D BF 54 10 E3 38 0D 36 D4 04 92 1C 20 DE 57 23 FF 54 1A 55 3D BE 5E
4C 96 B2 0E 32 80 D3 6D 40 48 70 83 79 5C 8F FD 50 69 54 F6 F9 96 48 A9 07 19
C2 30 F0 E1 BC AE 47 FE A8 34 AA 7B 7E 32 BF E5 1F EE A8 48 CA 11 87 87 0D E5
72 3F F5 41 A5 53 DB E5 24 5D F8 CA FF 4C B1 13 8C 71 18 7B C3 86 F2 B9 1F FA
A0 D2 A9 ED FD 55 97 BA 22 32 C0 D3 6D 40
```

Uncompressed file #1:

```
20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20
20 20 20 20 20 20 20 2A 2A 2A 2A 2A 20 47 52 41 4E 44 20 54 4F 54 41 4C 53 20
2A 2A 2A 2A 2A 0D 0A 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20
20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 54 4F 54 41 4C 20 52 45 43 4F 52 44
53 20 52 45 41 44 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 32 32 38 37 0D 0A
0D 0A 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20
20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 54 4F 54 41 4C 20 52 45 43 4F 52 44 53 20 42 59 50
41 53 53 45 44 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 32 32 38 37 0D 0A 20 20 20 20 20
20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20
20 20 54 4F 54 41 4C 20 52 45 43 4F 52 44 53 20 43 48 41 4E 47 45 44 20 20 20
20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 30 0D 0A 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20
20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 54 4F 54 41 4C
20 52 45 43 4F 52 44 53 20 4E 4F 54 20 4F 4E 20 58 52 45 46 20 20 20 20 20 20
20 20 20 20 30 0D 0A 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20
20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 54 4F 54 41 4C 20 52 45 43 4F 52 44
53 20 42 41 4E 4B 20 4E 4F 54 20 46 4F 55 4E 44 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 30 0D 0A
0D 0A 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20
20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 54 4F 54 41 4C 20 52 45 43 4F 52 44 53 20 57 52 49
54 54 45 4E 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 32 32 38 37
```

Uncompressed file #2:

```
20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20
20 20 20 20 20 20 20 2A 2A 2A 2A 2A 20 47 52 41 4E 44 20 54 4F 54 41 4C 53 20
2A 2A 2A 2A 2A 0D 0A 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20
20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 54 4F 54 41 4C 20 52 45 43 4F 52 44
53 20 52 45 41 44 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 33 34 33 39 0D 0A
0D 0A 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20
20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 54 4F 54 41 4C 20 52 45 43 4F 52 44 53 20 42 59 50
41 53 53 45 44 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 33 34 33 39 0D 0A 20 20 20 20 20
20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20
20 20 54 4F 54 41 4C 20 52 45 43 4F 52 44 53 20 43 48 41 4E 47 45 44 20 20 20
20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 30 0D 0A 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20
20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 54 4F 54 41 4C
20 52 45 43 4F 52 44 53 20 4E 4F 54 20 4F 4E 20 58 52 45 46 20 20 20 20 20 20
20 20 20 20 30 0D 0A 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20
20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 54 4F 54 41 4C 20 52 45 43 4F 52 44
53 20 42 41 4E 4B 20 4E 4F 54 20 46 4F 55 4E 44 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 30 0D 0A
0D 0A 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20
20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 54 4F 54 41 4C 20 52 45 43 4F 52 44 53 20 57 52 49
54 54 45 4E 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 33 34 33 39
```

As you can see, the output files are just plain ASCII text files. Any ideas?

Comment: Would it make sense to try compressing the uncompressed versions and compare the results?

Comment: The compressed versions are right there in the question -- I've highlighted the differing parts.

Comment: I think he means, try compressing the uncompressed versions using a few different algorithms and compare them to the compressed version you have up there...

Comment: Might be worth a try just trying a bunch of algorithms and comparing results...but if the algorithm isn't identically implemented, it may be different even though it's the same algorithm.  Plus, there are a bunch of algorithms out there.  :P

Comment: I did try several LZW variants -- but it would be really hard to find the correct algorithm that way, because of the large number of implementation details involved.

Comment: @stefan it's not a question, it's a subtle suggestion with the understanding that it might not work (as cHao suggested)  :)  Thanks to the others and yes I meant try compressing them with different algos and see which matches.

Comment: Where'd you get them from? (Can you say?)

Comment: @minitech -- I'm not sure about the source. A friend asked me to look at these, and it seemed interesting enough to explore.

Comment: For established compression formats, there is usually a "magic number" that will identify a compression format.  Have you tried using the Unix `file` command?  (you can inspect its user-readable database if you like; it will be located someplace like `/etc/magic` or `/usr/share/magic`)

Comment: @comingstorm -- that was one of the first things I tried, magic just responds with 'data.'

Comment: @comingstorm -- actually, I think it might be some known format -- but the format header is definitely missing. This appears to be just the raw compressed data.

Comment: Maybe it's DEFLATE, then? That's common, but you'd need to find out what was in the header...

Comment: @minitech -- DEFLATE is a possibility. Will need to re-create the header though, like you said -- trying that out.

Comment: Um, why are you showing your compressed data as groups of three hex digits?

Comment: @MarkAdler -- Well, I never expected the author of zlib to show up, for one! I was actually trying to make sense of the data, and it make more sense to me in 12-bit blocks -- hence the grouping. I'll fix it, if you think it makes more sense in groups of two.

Comment: Your grouping doesn't make sense to me. If you look at the bit stream, you can clearly see repeating patterns at uneven boundaries.

Comment: take `DE5 723 FF`, `<<1 == 1B CAE 47F`, `<<2 == 37 95C 8F`, etc. This holds for larger patterns, this is just to show the principle. Repeated bit strings coincide with repeated plaintext. (I added spaces so that you can locate the shifted pattern easily.)

Comment: @mvds -- I noticed those patterns too, but haven't really figured out where to go from there. Is it aligned on 6-bit boundaries? 12-bits? I'm not sure.

Comment: No, that's the point, they are not aligned at all. That means you are looking at a form of compression where there is no fixed token width. The only way to analyse the compressed data properly, is to look at the bit stream.

Comment: @mvds -- Hmm. Good point. I'll try doing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be some proprietary encoding format, designed to shave some bits of specific types of messages.

It operates on 8 bit (ascii) input and outputs a bit stream using a mixture of a 5 and 6 bit token set, including some control characters.

The following tokens can be identified:

```
// 5 bit tokens:
00000 switch to 6 bit mode
00011 take the following 6 bits as N, and output N spaces
00100 A
00101 B
.....
11101 Z
11110 <crlf>
11111 space

// 6 bit tokens:
000001 switch to 5 bit mode
000011 take the following 6 bits as N, and output N spaces
001001 <crlf>
011000 1
011001 2
......
100000 9

// pure speculation:
010111 0
010010 *
000110 repeat the next 6 bit char N times
001100 space
00001 skip 3 bits, take the next 8 bits as ascii, and output N times
```

Without more examples it is hard to determine what happens at the beginning of the stream. It might be some magic value, or could contain some control values.